# JavaScript replace img path

Tags: javascript

Hello JavaScript guru's. I have a simple JS question on how to replace all IMG src path's on a page.

Currently, my IMG tags look like:

> ```
> <img src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="" />
> ```

Output desired:

> ```
> <img src="../image.jpg" alt="" />
> ```

So, when a page is loaded, it will loop through all the IMG tags and replace the SRC path. Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Comment: I don't think it would work without reloading the page though

Comment: Yeah, it will work.  I do it with jQuery all the time.

Comment: Hi Drew, did you get this issue solved? If you found my answer useful, please check the "accept" checkmark. Thank you.

Comment: I did. Thanks to all for the great responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (var image, src, images = document.images, l=images.length, i=0; i<l; i++){
    image = images[i];
    src = image.src;
    image.src = ".." + src.substring(src.lastIndexOf("/"));
}
```